# Is there a way to increase the font size of IntelliSense?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to find that option in Visual Studio 2017. I know you can change the font of the code you're writing but not seeing the option for IntelliSense makes me think that is not possible.

[image]

Comment: It is there, Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > change the "Show settings for" selection.  "Statement completion" sets the font for the IntelliSense popup window, "Editor Tooltip" sets the font for the tooltip for a selection in the popup window.  Take an hour or two to click around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Comment: Did find which elements/options to set to change font etc. for the IntelliSense popup/tooltid?

Answer (score 25):

Tools – Options – Environment - Fonts and Colors > Statement Completion

- Besides "Editor Tooltip" option changes the method & parameter information

you can change size as you wish there.