# Visual Studio 2022 Text Editor ignores text scaling options

Tags: visual-studio

In Windows 10, I have "Make text bigger" set to 150%. This works fine in VS menu bar, context menus, solution explorer, etc, except in the Text Editor. This keeps using the same small text.

I can scale the editor itself to 150%, but then the code completion menu remains small... Is there anyway for VS to respect the "Make text bigger" in the text editor as well?

*I don't want to (further) increase my display scaling factor in Windows.*

Comment: The text editor scales text by itself, operate the scaling control on the lower left corner of the editor pane.

Comment: The text, yes, but not the code completion menu, it remains small even when you set it to 150%.

Comment: No real idea what a "code completion menu" might be.  Font size options are in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors.

Comment: The IntelliSense dialog: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/csharpintellisense-800x436.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084588/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-font-size-of-intellisense